# Deadlock when trying to call async method synchronously

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, asynchronous, xamarin

I know this question has been asked tons of times, but I couldn't find an answer which works for me.

I'm writing a Xamarin Forms app. In the Android project I need to override this method:

```
public override bool OnJsConfirm(WebView view, string url, string message, JsResult result)
```

So unfortunately I cannot make the method async.

Within that method I want to call this other one:

```
public static Task<bool> DisplayAlert(string title, string message, string accept, string cancel)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        var result = await MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, message, accept, cancel);
        tcs.SetResult(result);
    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The `MainPage.DisplayAlert()` needs to be called on the UI thread which my method ensures.

I already tried to call my `DisplayAlert` from the synchronous `OnJsConfirm` method with these variants:

```
//bool success = UI.DisplayAlert(title, message, ok, cancel).Result;                                // hangs !!!
//bool success = UI.DisplayAlert(title, message, ok, cancel).WaitAndUnwrapException();              // hangs !!! WaitAndUnwrapException is in Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous
//bool success = Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(() => UI.DisplayAlert(title, message, ok, cancel));  // hangs !!!
//bool success = TaskEx.Run(() => UI.DisplayAlert(title, message, ok, cancel)).Result;              // hangs !!!
//bool success = Task.Run(() => UI.DisplayAlert(title, message, ok, cancel)).Result;                // hangs !!!
//bool success = Task.Run(async () => await UI.DisplayAlert(title, message, ok, cancel)).Result;    // hangs !!!
bool success = Task.Run(async () => await UI.DisplayAlert(title, message, ok, cancel).ConfigureAwait(false)).Result;    // hangs !!!
```

I took the suggestions using Nito.AsyncEx from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/1722408) by Stephen Cleary to a similar question.

I also already tried to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to the `await MainPage.DisplayAlert(...)`, but that also didn't work.

When I set a breakpoint at the `await MainPage.DisplayAlert` line, then it was hit in all but the last two variants and when I then pressed F10, VS2015 stopped with this call stack:
[image]

There was no exception though. The app just hang.

Does anybody know, how I can call my async method?

Comment: It looks like you are calling DisplayAlert inside DisplayAlert so you will just keep calling it forever hence the app hanging

Comment: Shot in the dark that might work `new Handler().Post(new Runnable(async () => //code));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of [OnJsConfirm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onJsConfirm(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.JsResult)) only indicates, if you will handle the confirm dialog. So you need to return true and do the rest asynchronously. And if your `DisplayAlert` returns, you can call `Confim()` or `Cancel()` on the `JsResult` depending on the task's result.

```
public override bool OnJsConfirm(WebView view, string url, string message, JsResult result)
{
    DisplayAlert("Really?", message, "OK", "Cancel").ContinueWith(t => {
        if(t.Result) {
            result.Confirm();
        }
        else {
            result.Cancel();
        }
    });
    return true;
}


public static Task<bool> DisplayAlert(string title, string message, string accept, string cancel)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        var result = await MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, message, accept, cancel);
        tcs.SetResult(result);
    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```